# Issues with social buttons on fancybox

Tags: jquery, iframe, fancybox, facebook-social-plugins, tweets

I am using the jsfiddle below to add social buttons on my fancybox title. I have two issues

1) The like button doesn't appear, when using "this.href" code for the href, although it works on the jsfiddle.

2) When I use the tweet share button, it shares the title of my website, although on the jsfiddle it displays the title + the image url. Is it possible to display the IFRAME title & url instead?(as you can see on jsfiddle my fancybox type is iframe).

JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/kmLWf/44/

```
$.fancybox.update();
    $('.iframe').fancybox({         

    beforeShow: function () {if (this.title) {
            // New line
            this.title += '<br />';

            // Add tweet button
            this.title += '<a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-count="none" data-url="' + this.href + '">Tweet</a> ';

            // Add FaceBook like button
            this.title += '<iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=' + this.href + '&amp;layout=button_count&amp;show_faces=true&amp;width=500&amp;action=like&amp;font&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;height=23" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:110px; height:23px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>';}},
    afterShow: function() {
        // Render tweet button
        twttr.widgets.load();
    },
    href:this.href,
    padding:0,
    type:'iframe',
    scrolling : "no",
    prevEffect      : 'fade',
    nextEffect      : 'fade',
    preload:true,
    autoSize : false, 
    autoCenter: true, 
    fitToView : false, 
    loop: false,
    helpers : {
        overlay : {
        css : {
            'background' : 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7)',
            'overflow-y': 'hidden'
                },
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding absolute URL's on my image href's fixed the issue.